# Does my QuickBooks Online App need to run in a separate window or tab? Are there apps that run like plugins, within the same window as QB Online?

Tags: plugins, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am currently developing a QuickBooks Online App. Many of the existing apps in the Quickbooks Online store run in a separate window or tab within the browser. The applications have their own User Interface running in a separate window/tab.

Can I develop a QuickBooks Online application that acts more similarly to a plugin?

We want the users to remain in their current instance of QuickBooks Online, and use our application as a plugin--adding services & functionality.

We would like to avoid running our app in its own separate window/tab.

Do you think I'd be better off developing as browser plugin for Chrome?

One problem may be Intuit's OAuth 2.0 requirements. We wouldn't be able to access the user's QuickBooks information without going through the OAuth Flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *do* need to go through the OAuth flow to get access to QuickBooks data.

QuickBooks does *not* let you embed any components or UI inside of QuickBooks, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: My application will need a UI in another window/tab within the browser, then the user will have to export whatever my app does into their instance of QBO?

Comment: EDIT: sorry, I should have specified more information. My application wants to create a Service Item within QuickBooks for someone. My app will need to perform this operation in a separate window & export it?

Comment: You can't embed things within QuickBooks Online, so your app needs to be _somewhere_ else. Maybe in a separate tab. Maybe it's running on your computer in the console/CLI. Maybe it's in a separate browser. Maybe it's just on some server somewhere doing stuff in the background. QuickBooks doesn't care. You just make your API calls from wherever to tell QuickBooks to create the item.